# Implications of JavaScript same origin policy on dynamic image loading

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

If JavaScript has a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), does that mean that I can't dynamically load images from a different domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the same origin policy does not apply to `<img>` tags.

There are other notable exceptions, some of which are described in that Wikipedia article.  They include:

- Style-sheets
- Scripts (this is how [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) works)
- Form submissions

Comment: @Mathew- thanks- do other exceptions to SOP exist? - I can't find a good reference on that

Comment: The same-origin policy does apply to loading an image into an HTML5 canvas element, but that's the only way it applies to images. You can do document.getElementById('img').src = 'http://some.other.domain/foo.jpg' or `var i = new Image(); i.src='...';` and there will be no problem.

Comment: @Yarin: HTML form submissions, JavaScript/CSS loading, and framing are also not subject to the SOP. In some browsers, XMLHttpRequest can bypass the SOP if the third-party server approves it with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Life_outside_same-origin_rules

Comment: @idealmachine- that's interesting- why the restriction on HTML5 Canvas do you think?

Comment: @Yarin: Most of the exceptions to the same-origin policy date back to the earliest days of Netscape Navigator and other browsers. Actually, you can load an image cross-domain into a canvas, but you are not able to access individual pixels anymore of the canvas using `getImageData`.

Comment: @Mathew- JSONP... that's something I need to check out

Answer (score 2):

The same-origin policy is limited to document properties of another site. Images are not considered as document properties.

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-Security/

Comment: Wrong. They are when you want to examine their pixels.